# Передача данных в ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, веб-программирование

В общем задача такова: мне надо передать массив(с помощью ajax наверное) с контроллера на js.
Вот мой контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getProducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ProductDTO[] getProducts() {
    List<ProductDTO> productDTOs = pService.findAllProductDTOs();
    ProductDTO[] products = new ProductDTO[productDTOs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < productDTOs.size(); i++) {
       products[i] = productDTOs.get(i);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Нужно передать его в js-файл, записав в `var product = *массив*`,
чтобы в дальнейшем с ним работать.

Comment: ну, раз надо - значит передавайте :)   в чем вопрос-то? что-то попробовали? что-то не получилось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getProducts",
    method: "get",
    success: function (res){
    }
});
```

res - это и есть данные, которые возвращаются.